# use SPLIT function to seperate a list of numbers from a userform

Tags: excel, vba, split, userform

I have a userform that has a list of numbers entered in column style with no separator other than being on a separate line.  Entry into the user form will look something like this:

```
2172223333
2172223334
2172223335
2172223336
2172223337
```

How do I use the SPLIT function to separate this bulk entry into the user form into separate cells in the same column on a spreadsheet?  I'm familiar with how it works if there is a comma or space to look for between the terms but will it somehow recognize a separate line as a delineator and if so, what symbol do I use to represent that in the code?

I want to be able to read this input and have it entered in a workbook, say ("workbookA") and sheets(1) and put it in Column A starting at row 2 and going downward staying in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myString = ...
data = split(myString, vbcrlf)
workbooks("workbookA").worksheets(1).range("A2").resize(ubound(data)+1,1).value = application.transpose(data)
```

**myString** is the String with your data.

In VBA you have the constants `vbLf`, `vbCr`, `vbCrLf` for linefeed, carriage return and linefeed + carriage return (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), which represent the characters.

Comment: awesome, I'll try that and let you know how it works.